# Data URI in css file for dynamic content

Tags: html, css, performance, http

We have a third party service of news that returns 10 news in 1 http request. Each news has one image url with it. We have to make 10 http requests to download those images. This app will run on mobile so it's becoming slow. We are looking for some solution. I have used data uri in css files before. Is there any way it can be done in our case where data is dynamic and loaded at runtime? Please suggest if there is some solution to this problem. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you process your data dynamically, you can merge the 10 images in one file and use CSS image sprites to show only the portion corresponding to your article.